# Find a KNP-KQ endgame in which Black loses

Tags: endgame, problems, queen-endgame

How do I find a position where Black, on move, cannot save themselves from defeat, having a king and queen against White's king, knight, and pawn? Furthermore, Black is not in check.

Answer (score 12):

```
[Title "White plays and wins (note the position after 2 Kg6)"]
[FEN "4N2k/8/6PK/q7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0"]

1. g7+ Kg8 2. Kg6 Qb6+ 3. Nf6+ Qxf6 4. Kxf6 Kh7 5. Kf7 1-0
```

If Black stops 3 Nf6# with Qf5(g5,h5)+ then 3 Kxh5 and the Ne8 still holds
the Pg7 so White soon wins.  The bottom edge of the board barely prevents
Black from turning the tables with 2 ... Qa0+.

Comment: OP states that it should be Black to move first. Therefore, this answer is not valid. However, the position after 2.Kg6 can be considered valid, I guess.

Comment: A general good idea for this type of question is checking https://ulthiel.com/math/other/endgames/ to see if there is a win at all. (Of course, the additional conditions by the asker make most of the known wins invalid.) Giving that the longest win for White is 36 moves, there must be an even trickier answer possible that the one by Noam.

Comment: W: K g6, p g7, N е8
Б: K g8, Q а5